# What is this rewrite rule doing, exactly?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I don't read regex very well. Can someone help me understand what exactly this is doing?

```
RewriteRule ^[!/.]*([\/A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php
```

I have a basic idea, just not concrete clarity, and I don't want to miss something important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will match on a url that

- starts with a !, / or . and
- is followed by a forward slash, capital letter or digit.

All requests for URLs that match this rule will be sent to index.php.

This is a very unusual RewriteRule as it enables URLs like:

```
http://example.com/!asdf 
http://example.com/!.asdf2
http://example.com/!./asdf5
http://example.com/./asdf5
http://example.com/.asdf5
```

This type of rewrite rule is typically intended to direct requests for files/directories that don't exist to a front controller. Something like this may serve you better:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Comment: Thanks again, this did help me think in the right direction. I ended up with this regex for the rule: ^([\/\-?#A-Za-z0-9]+)$